# Zend DB SELECT with JOIN from database

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am trying to solve my problem since 2 hours and still I don't have any solution. Maybe someone will see what am I doing wrong.
What I'm trying to do is to SELECT rows from database using zend framework. 
This is query what I want to select:

```
SELECT * FROM `products_stock` JOIN `options_stock_values` ON `options_stock_values`.`stock_id` = `products_stock`.`stock_id` WHERE `product_id` = 119
```

It's a simple JOIN which works perfect in phpmyadmin, but I my php code can't select this in way I want.

```
        $select = $this->entity("ProductsStock")->select();
        $select->join('options_stock_values','options_stock_values.stock_id = products_stock.stock_id',array());
        $select->where("product_id = ?", $this->stock->product_id);
        $select->where("extended = ?", 1);
        $rowset = $this->entity("ProductsStock")->fetchAll($select);

        return $rowset;
```

This is how I am trying to select my rows from database. I am selecting ProductsStock from entity which works fine. But when I add JOIN function to my query it even ignores WHERE statements and give me multiple rows expect that one row.

For e.g. 
With that db query without JOIN I am getting two rows (and I am expecting them), but when I add JOIN with options_stock_values table it gives me something like 20 rows without columns from sencond table.

It just returns 20 rows from first table (ProductsStock) instead of two rows from ProductsStock joined with OptionsStockValues and with columns from that second table.

I think that my php code looks fine, but maybe I did something wrong with it? Can anyone help me and give me even small advice?

Comment: Could you please mention the zend framework version?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest including the FROM clause in your select object:

```
$select = $this->entity("ProductsStock")->select();
$select->from(array('p'=>'products_stock'),array('*'))
    ->join(array('o'=>'options_stock_values'),'p.stock_id=o.stock_id',array('*'))
    ->where('product_id = ?',119);
```

Without seeing your table data, I don't know if you will get the results you are seeking but this code represents the SQL you provided at the top of your question.